# NSPredicate problem with column name

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I am trying to query a table using NSPredicate. Here is essentially what I'm doing:

```
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInteger: 2];
NSString *columnName = @"something_id";

NSLog(@"%@ == %@", columnName, value);
NSPredicate *refQuery = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"%@ == %@", columnName, value];
```

NSLog prints out what I expect ("something_id == 2"), but the predicate doesn't work.
However, the predicate DOES work if I change it to:

```
NSPredicate *refQuery = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"something_id == %@", value];
```

So why won't this work and how can I fix it?

Comment: That is very odd... happens to me too..

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[The Predicate Programming Guide from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-SW1) says:

> %@ is a var arg substitution for an
> object value—often a string, number,
> or date.
>
> %K is a var arg substitution
> for a key path.
>
> When string variables
> are substituted into a format string
> using %@ , they are surrounded by
> quotation marks. If you want to
> specify a dynamic property name, use
> %K in the format string.

So, in your case, you need to put %K as a keypath to columnName, not %@ which will be added with quotation marks:

```
NSPredicate *refQuery = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"%K == %@", columnName, value];
```

Hope this clear your doubts.

Comment: FWIW you will probably want to use %K on both sides of the predicate, as integer substitutions will be erroneously wrapped in double quotes.

Comment: Nope, value is not an integer, but it's an NSNumber, as you can see in the documentation, it's the right format.

Answer (score 1):

Very weird, but I think I have solved it by doing the following:

```
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInteger: 2];
NSString *columnName = @"something_id";

NSString *predicate = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ == %@", columnName, value];
NSPredicate *refQuery = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: predicate];
```

Comment: If anyone can shed some light on why this happens I would be very grateful.

Comment: Because here you give "something_id == 2", if you let predicate format the string, it will output this: "something_id" == 2, so the field will become a string and not a field without quotes